# YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TY error in using PCL with VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, eigen, point-cloud-library, slam-algorithm

I am compiling an opensource c++ program which uses PCL and OPENCV. The problem seems to be types transformation between different Eigen objects.

> `c:\program files (x86)\pcl 1.6.0\3rdparty\eigen\include\eigen\src\core\matrix.h(294): error C2338:`
>   `YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY`

Code about Eigen in the program:

```
    cv::Mat R;
cv::Rodrigues( result.rvec, R );
Eigen::Matrix3d r;
cv::cv2eigen(R, r);

// 将平移向量和旋转矩阵转换成变换矩阵
Eigen::Isometry3d T = Eigen::Isometry3d::Identity();

Eigen::AngleAxisd angle(r);
cout<<"translation"<<endl;
Eigen::Translation<double,3> trans(result.tvec.at<double>(0,0), result.tvec.at<double>(0,1), result.tvec.at<double>(0,2));
T = angle;
T(0,3) = result.tvec.at<double>(0,0); 
T(1,3) = result.tvec.at<double>(0,1); 
T(2,3) = result.tvec.at<double>(0,2);

// Transform point clouds
cout<<"converting image to clouds"<<endl;
PointCloud::Ptr cloud1 = image2PointCloud( frame1.rgb, frame1.depth, camera );
PointCloud::Ptr cloud2 = image2PointCloud( frame2.rgb, frame2.depth, camera );

// Combine point clouds
cout<<"combining clouds"<<endl;
PointCloud::Ptr output (new PointCloud());
pcl::transformPointCloud( *cloud1, *output, T.matrix() );   // error occurs at this line, the compiler told.
*output += *cloud2;
```

error message:

> 1>c:\program files (x86)\pcl
>   1.6.0\3rdparty\eigen\include\eigen\src\core\matrix.h(294): error C2338:
>   YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_
>   TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY
>       1>          f:\cpps\win32project1\win32project1\jointpointcloud.cpp(88) : see
>   reference to function template instantiation
>   'Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar,_Rows,_Cols>::Matrix(const
>   Eigen::MatrixBase &)' being compiled
>       1>          with
>       1>          [
>       1>              _Scalar=float,
>       1>              _Rows=4,
>       1>              _Cols=4,
>       1>              Derived=Eigen::Matrix
>       1>          ]
>       1>          f:\cpps\win32project1\win32project1\jointpointcloud.cpp(88) : see
>   reference to function template instantiation
>   'Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar,_Rows,_Cols>::Matrix(const
>   Eigen::MatrixBase &)' being compiled
>       1>          with
>       1>          [
>       1>              _Scalar=float,
>       1>              _Rows=4,
>       1>              _Cols=4,
>       1>              Derived=Eigen::Matrix
>       1>          ]
>       ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: This step can be a problem `T = angle;`. Instead you should use `T = (Eigen::Isometry3d)angle;`

Comment: Could you be more specific which line actually causes the problem? The line mentioned by @TheApache does not involve numeric type conversion, so I don't think it is the reason for the error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide us more information about your problem. In particular, please post a [mcve] and the _full_ error message you are getting. From the information provided, we cannot currently tell what the problem is.

Comment: I updated the error message.

Comment: @TheApache I have updated the error message. I failed to solve it today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transformPointCloud` methods in PCL 1.6 expect the transformation matrix to be in float format ([link](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.6.0/group__common.html#ga3bc825d49213ab56ea958b2f1d0f21c0)).
You need to write

```
pcl::transformPointCloud( *cloud1, *output, T.cast<float>() );
```

The `.matrix()` conversion is actually not necessary.

Comment: That is perfectly solved that error. Thank you, chtz.